# Java Manual Camera Driver

Tags: java, camera

Does anyone know the algorithm used in connecting manually in the camera.
I would like to connect with my camera and show the image taken from the camera to a jframe.
As much as possible I dont want to use any API for my program. This is for the sake of study and not a large project. I just want to know the background workings of java and see it with my own eyes.

Comment: It will depend on the type if camera

Comment: Its a built-in camera in a netbook. The driver is Realtek I think..

Comment: this might help. http://webcam-capture.sarxos.pl/

Comment: Also this: http://www.tricksmode.com/2013/03/How-To-Capture-Webcam-Images-In-Java-Swings.html

Comment: As much as possible I would like to do it without using any api or libraries. The purpose of this project is for learning and would like to see how java works from ground-up.